# Android Media Support

Tags: android

I want to know whether following media are supported **natively** in Android or not I am not sure about `Audio/Video` as I am not well versed with media formats, so please enlighten me on following formats. I had already referenced http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

1. **WMA** file (As per my knowledge not supported)
2. **Flash Media only Audio H.264 MP4**( I dont know much about flash but only this that we can play flash file in android 2.2+ using `webview`)
3. **Quick Time only Audio H.264 MP4**
4. **Real Media**

Regards
Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

You can find the list of supported formats here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I had already checked that but I am not sure whether my formats are there in it or not as I am not good at them :(

Comment: ok, then I don't know anything more than you know I guess. But as far as I understand, #1, #4 not supported; #2 & #3 are supported. I'm not sure though.